# NoSuchMethodError when switching from camunda extension to camunda base module

Tags: java, camunda

I just saw that the Maven artifact org.camunda.bpm.extension:camunda-bpm-junit5 has not seen updates lately but seems to have been incorporated into org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bpm-junit5. So I tried to switch to the new package. This comes with some package changes, apparently.

I tried to just replace the package name for ProcessEngineExtension in my code from

`import org.camunda.bpm.extension.junit5.test.ProcessEngineExtension;`

to

`import org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.junit5.ProcessEngineExtension;`

This does compile, however the unit tests fail with this ominous error (I am not using the below TestHelper class myself):

`NoSuchMethodError: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.test.TestHelper.annotationDeploymentSetUp`

The weirdest part is that Maven is not showing me any stack trace (static initializer problem?); this is the kind of output I get:

````
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.test.TestHelper.annotationDeploymentSetUp(
Lorg/camunda/bpm/engine/ProcessEngine;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;
Lorg/camunda/bpm/engine/test/Deployment;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Have you adjusted the other dependencies (jUnit, bpm-assert) and packages to jUnit 5 and the bootstrapping of the engine to the new way?

Please see full examples here:
https://camunda.com/blog/2021/01/test-your-processes-with-junit-5/

and here:

https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-bpm-junit5/blob/master/examples/camunda-bpm-assert/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/unittest/SimpleTestCase.java

If this does not help please add the test case code (imports, bootstrap, 1 test) to your question.